# How to push data in a dropdown into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner of React.I'm trying to push the values in the select component() to an array called tagIdList...But I'm getting an error called 
TypeError: fieldValues.tagsList.map is not a function

How to solve this? Following is my code..

```
if (JSON.stringify(fieldValues && fieldValues.productId) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.fieldValues && prevProps.fieldValues.productId)) {
    let tagIdList = [];
    debugger
    fieldValues && fieldValues.tagsList && fieldValues.tagsList.map(tag => tagIdList.push(tag.value));

    if (tagIdList.length === 0) {
        earlyBirdsActions.getProduct(fieldValues.productId);
    } else {
        let data = {
            "tags": tagIdList,
            "typeId": fieldValues && fieldValues.productId
        }
        earlyBirdsActions.getProductWithTypeAndTags(data);
    }

}

if (JSON.stringify(fieldValues && fieldValues.tagsList) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.fieldValues && prevProps.fieldValues.tagsList)) {
    let tagIdList = [];
    debugger
    fieldValues && fieldValues.tagsList && fieldValues.tagsList.map(tag => tagIdList.push(tag.value));

    if (tagIdList.length === 0) {
        earlyBirdsActions.getProduct(fieldValues.productId);
    } else {
        let data = {
            "tags": tagIdList,
            "typeId": fieldValues.productId
        }
        earlyBirdsActions.getProductWithTypeAndTags(data);
    }

}
```

The above code is within componentDidUpdate.

And the following is the select compoennt.

```
<Row>
                            <div className="col-md-4" style={{ paddingBottom: "15px" }}>
                                <label>Tag List</label>
                                {/* <Field type='reselect' name="tagsList" component={InputField} options={arrayTagList} /> */}
                                <Field
                                    type="select"
                                    className="form-control mb-2"
                                    name="tagsList"
                                    component={InputField}
                                    disabled={disabled}
                                >

                                    {tagList && tagList.tagData && tagList.tagData.map(
                                        (option, index) => {
                                            return (
                                                // <option value={option.id}>{option.tag}</option>
                                                <option value={option.tag}>{option.tag}</option>
                                            )
                                        }
                                    )}
                                </Field>
                            </div>
                        </Row>
```

Comment: Is it react-bootstrap?

Comment: yes and redux form